# Amazon s3- Paperclip can't upload images to proper path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a rails app that users can upload photos to. The photos get uploaded to Amazon S3 bucket. I have a "Contributor" who has many "Listings" which a "Listing" has many "Images". What I would like it to upload all of the images to this type of directory:

```
:contributor_id/:listing_id/IMAGES_HERE.jpg
```

I would also like it so that if a contributor creates another listing, it doesn't create a whole entire new folder for that contributor. I want it to upload it to the already created folder with the contributor id.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this? Here is what my current :path looks like

```
  has_attached_file :asset,
                :styles => {:large => "640x480", :medium => "300x300", :thumb => "100x100" },
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                :path => "/:contributor_id/:id/:filename"
```

**ANSWER:**

Thanks so much for your answers. here is how I got it to work, using the Interpolations feature of Paperclip.

```
Paperclip.interpolates('contributor_id') do |attachment, style|
 attachment.instance.listing.contributor_id
end

Paperclip.interpolates('listing_name') do |attachment, style|
 attachment.instance.listing.title.parameterize
end
```

And then my path..

```
:path => "/:contributor_id/:listing_name/:filename"
```

Comment: did you setup s3.yml properly ?

Comment: Yes, this file is setup properly. I have no problem getting the uploads to work. I am just looking for how i can customize the upload directory structure that they get uploaded to, and how to not create duplicate folder names based on the contributor id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but there is like it usually do:

```
module Paperclip      
  module Interpolations

    def timestamp attachment, style
      attachment.instance_read(:updated_at).to_i
    end

  end
end
```

And I think it should looks like:

```
module Paperclip      
   module Interpolations

     def contributor_id attachment, style
       attachment.instance_read(:contributor_id)
     end

   end
end
```

You could read more about PaperClip's custom interpolations [here](http://viget.com/extend/paperclip-custom-interpolation)

Comment: I think I should be able to edit the :path credential to get the proper directory structure. Any idea on how to not duplicate folder names that get created? If contributor (:id => 2) uploads multiple photos i don't want to have multiple folders named "2". I'd like to always have images get uploaded inside their own folder each time.

Comment: Have you tested it? If you have path like in your example _/:contributor_id/:id/:filename_ you will have a only one folder for each contributor's id ( like in your file system ). So, if you're uploading several images to your listing ( with id = 1 ) which belongs to some contributor ( id = 2 ) than you will get file tree like this: _/2/1/image_1.jpg_, _/2/1/image_2.jpg_, _/2/1/image_n.jpg_ ... Where _/2_ and _/2/1_ are same for all attachments.

Comment: Make sure to use _:path => "/:contributor_id/:id/:filename.:extension"_ to save files within theirs extensions.

Comment: attachment.instance_read(:updated_at).to_i is something that does not work if the image gets updated